# DELETE FROM ... USING deletes no rows when referenced table is empty

Tags: postgresql

I want to delete rows from table `A` optionally based on input (column `name`) that is available only in table `B`.  The two tables are related on column `id`. Based on the Postgres (9.6) docs for `DELETE` and a few answers here on SO, it seemed like the `USING` clause was appropriate:

```
DELETE FROM A a
USING B b
WHERE $1 IS NULL OR (b.name = $1 AND a.id = b.id)
```

and indeed, this seemed to work (if `$1` is `NULL`, then delete all rows from `A`; otherwise only those rows in `A` which share `id` with rows in `B` whose `name` is `$1`). But I ended up running this in a situation where `B` was empty, and found that even when `$1 IS NULL` was applicable, no rows got deleted from `A`.  I even reduced this to no `WHERE` clause:

```
DELETE FROM A
USING B
```

and as long as `B` is empty, that deletes nothing from `A`.  The equivalent using a sub-select works as I expect:

```
DELETE FROM A a
WHERE $1 IS NULL OR a.name IN (
    SELECT a.name
    FROM A a, B b
    WHERE b.name = $1 AND a.id = b.id
)
```

The [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-delete.html#AEN85428) don't strictly rule this difference out, but they don't say anything about its possibility, either:

> PostgreSQL lets you reference columns of other tables in the WHERE condition by specifying the other tables in the USING clause. ...  What is essentially happening here is a join [...], with all successfully joined [...] rows being marked for deletion.  In some cases the join style is easier to write or faster to execute than the sub-select style.

Maybe there's another page somewhere I should read? Or does "successfully joined rows" imply that there must be a join?

Comment: I think that "successfully joined rows" does imply that.

Comment: Note: the two queries are **not** equivalent. (and `EXISTS()` is your friend)

Comment: Well, clearly they're not equivalent. :) Could you add some detail to how and why, and how and why `EXISTS()` would help?